# JQuery + Flowplayer: flowplayer cannot access element

Tags: javascript, jquery, flowplayer

I want to insert a Flowplayer into a div created entirely with JQuery (using `.append()`).

When execution gets to this point:

```
$div.attr('id', 'flowplayer');
flowplayer('flowplayer', 'flowplayer/flowplayer-3.2.7.swf');
```

UPDATE:
**No more exception**, the player just doesn't appear. No errors appear on my console.

What am I missing?

(What's posted above is not my actual code, and I may have the wrong idea of what's relevant and what's not, so if you need to see more code, please ask)

Comment: $(div) instead of $div ?

Comment: @Satish Nope, `$div = $('bla');`, I use the `$` to mark JQuery objects among my variables.

Comment: @has the div definitely been added to the DOM yet before calling the reference to the id?

Comment: try doing a console.log to print out and check if the "id"exists

Comment: @Brian duh, I was about to answer 'yes' and decided to recheck my code. I had confused a variable name, and for some reason fate decided that the script could run without errors using the other name. HOWEVER: now, without complaining, nothing happens

Answer (score 2):

If "$div" is your jQuery object have you tried:

```
flowplayer($div.get(0), 'flowplayer/flowplayer-3.2.7.swf');
```

There is a method which take a DOM element in the documentation [Flowplayer documentation](http://flowplayer.org/documentation/api/flowplayer.html)

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I'm using the jQuery integration now, which looks cleaner, but still doesn't work =( nothing happens when I call `flowplayer()`

Answer (score 1):

Same problem I faced today..found solution for this.

The reason was that the script was loaded in the header apparently. By default the Javascript placement in SWF Tools' Embedding settings (admin/settings/swftools/embed) is set to "Body".

I switched this to "Header" - something I shouldn't have done. After searching all the way around I eventually find out that this was the culprit for the behaviour described above. I switched it back to "Body", which solved the problem.

Enjoy..

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use **.live()**:

**.live()** - Attach an event handler for all elements which match the current selector, now and in the future. http://api.jquery.com/live/

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether the API has changed or something like that but, we used to just have the elements as  elements, without the use of a div.  Simply adding the div worked for us.